# SearchView shows only one & same record from listView with CustomAdapter but searchView works fine with ArrayAdapter. Here's my adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, custom-adapter

```
import com.example.mis_internee.atendence_app_android.R;


    public class EMP_LEAVE_ADAPTER extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] itemname;

        public EMP_LEAVE_ADAPTER(Activity context, String[] itemname) {
            super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.context = context;
            this.itemname = itemname;


        }
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_leave_adpater_layout, null,true);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            ImageView image=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
            return rowView;

        };
    }
```

Comment: where is search filter method in your code?

Comment: SearchView is in Activity , its is working when i write " arratAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);" but when i use this adapter " ELA.getFilter().filter(newText);" it shows only first row of list

Comment: that's why i am asking you created custom adapter for search so you have to implement filter method for filter text.

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.viewaprovedlist, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

Comment: public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        ELA.getFilter().filter(newText);
//
//        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
//            listView.clearTextFilter();
//        }
//        else {
//            listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
//        }

        return true;
    }

Comment: posted in comment

Comment: @KamranIjaz please edit your question with the code instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return different view and also you need to recycle the view manually as follows:

```
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
 ViewHolder viewHolder;
 if(view == null) {
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
   View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_leave_adpater_layout, null,true);

  viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
  viewHolder.image=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
  view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }   
  viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);

  return viewHolder;
};


public class viewholder {

 public TextView txtTitle;
 public ImageView image;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response , i used adapter for text and image , it is showing fine but when i add searchView and search with name it shows only that name which is on top, and if search text out of list then no row shows

Comment: you want to hide rows when there is search text out of list right..?

Comment: no i just want to show that row which i search like if is search "A" from list 
A
B
C
D
it Will show "A" but when i Search "B" it shows again A but when i search "XYZ" which is not in list it shows nothing.

Comment: ok. once you get response from API, update the arraylist data/ and refresh the adapter using adapter.notifydatasetchanged(). Add null check for preventing refresh, if there is no results..

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement filter class in your custom adapter and call this method from your class, have look

in your adapter :

```
 public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

**Now in your activity where  edittext  is defined :**

```
editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

        mSearchableAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

change according to your requirement, hope it will help you!!